# I want to ask about elementary matlab coding

Tags: matlab, fibonacci

The problem is:

Write a Matlab program using loops to compute the first 100 Fibonacci numbers: a1=1, a2=1 an=an-1 + an-2(n>=3)

My first answer was

```
function y = fibonacci100

a(1)=1, a(2)=1; 

for t = 1 : 98

a(t+2) = a(t+1) + a(t)

end

y= a(t+2)
```

But I read the problem thoroughly and I noticed that my answer was wrong, because of the "the first 100 Fibonacci numbers"

I don't understand how to do it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fibonacci sequence should begin with `a1 = 0` and `a2 = 1`, otherwise your code looks correct to me assuming you only want to output the last number in the sequence.

If you want to output the entire sequence then just get rid of `y` and output `a` instead:

```
function a = fibonacci100
% your code...
```

Comment: Really thank for your reply. Could you explain why should I begin with a1=0 more specifically?

Comment: That is just simply the first value in the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: That really is just splitting hairs. The starting value can be either 0 or 1 depending on preference, with the sequence used by Fibonacci starting at 1.

Comment: The Last Question:

I changed my code as:


function a = fibonacci100
a = zeros(100,1);
a(1)=1, a(2)=1; 
for t = 1 : 98
a(t+2) = a(t+1) + a(t);
end
y= a(t+2);
format long g

//I wonder why I should write y=a(t+2) why y? we are talking about function "a" but at last we use y.